# How can i mock method that has HtttpRequestBase parameter

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

I have method:

```
public override someClass getX(HttpRequestBase request){ ... }
```

now, I want to mock it.

I tried

```
mockProvider.Setup(x => x.getX(It.IsAny<HttpRequestWrapper>())).Returns(someClassInstance);
```

but it return null, not someClassInstance (by debug i can see it's not null).
what can i do? thanks!

Comment: you have a typo in `x.GetX(It.IsAny<HttpRequestWrapper>())` should not be `x.getX(It.IsAny<HttpRequestWrapper>())`?

Comment: `getX` returns `int` so it returns 0 by default (not `null`). Are you sure problem is in this method?

Comment: @Elph,  this typo is only here. I just tried to simplify the situation. 
but the core idea is: what can i insert into it.isAny<> in this case

Comment: @Alexander, it's not the point. i change the example to be object like in my code. see also above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly understand why you expecte the result to be "2" nor can i see the declaration of `someClassInstance` to verify if the Assert should or should not be NULL.

However, I implemented those Methods and wrapped a test around:

```
using System.Web;

using Moq;

using NUnit.Framework;

public class FooBase
{
    public virtual ResultObject getX(HttpRequestBase request)
    {
        return new ResultObject { Id = 2 };
    }
}

public class Foo : FooBase
{
    public override ResultObject getX(HttpRequestBase request)
    {
        return new ResultObject { Id = 4 };
    }
}

public class ResultObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

[TestFixture]
public  class Test
{
    Mock<Foo> mockProvider = new Mock<Foo>();

    [Test]
    public void FooTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var fakedResultObject = new ResultObject { Id = 8 };
        mockProvider.Setup(x => x.getX(It.IsAny<HttpRequestWrapper>())).Returns(fakedResultObject);

        // Act
        var result = mockProvider.Object.getX(new HttpRequestWrapper(new HttpRequest("filename", "http://foo.org", "querystring")));

        //Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(8, result.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe it's another problem, ask again in
http://stackoverflow.com/q/33532536/3202422
thanks