# Using moq on an override of abstract method?

Tags: c#, moq

I have this base class

```
public abstract class Third : IThird
{
    public abstract ThirdUser GetUserDetails(HttpRequestBase request);
}
```

and this derived class

```
public class LiProvider : Third
{
    public override ThirdUser GetUserDetails(HttpRequestBase request) { }
}
```

I tried to Moq this override like so:

```
mockLiProvider.Setup(x => x.GetUserDetails(It.IsAny<HttpRequestWrapper>())).Returns(user);
```

but it returns `null`, not the `user` in the `Setup`.

`user` is definitely initialised in this test.

How can I mock this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't it be

```
mockLiProvider.Setup(x => x.GetUserDetails(It.IsAny<HttpRequestBase>())).Returns(user);
```

instead of

```
mockLiProvider.Setup(x => x.GetUserDetails(It.IsAny<HttpRequestWrapper>())).Returns(user);#
```

Notice the different type in `It.IsAny<>`, I've used `HttpRequestBase` instead of `HttpRequestWrapper`.

---

You example doesn't show how it is been called.

I wrote this simple test calling it like this:

```
mockLiProvider.Object
.GetUserDetails(new HttpRequestWrapper(new HttpRequest("a.txt","http://a.com","")));
```

and it works, with your version (`HttpRequestWrapper`). 
But if you are supplied some other derivative of `HttpRequestBase` the `It.IsAny` might not match the type.